# BindingList error when removing Item

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a problem when removing entrys from a BindingList in connection with a DataGridView
Here some informations first:

I have a class

```
public class DeliveryTimeList<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IDeliveryTimeObject where T : IDeliveryTimeData
```

which implements this interface

```
public interface IDeliveryTimeObject : IListSource
```

I use this DeliveryTimeList in a DataGridView.

My class contains a List with visible objects

```
private List<T> _visibleList;
```

Because i implement the IListSource i have this Method

```
public IList GetList()
{
    BindingList<T> blt = new BindingList<T>(_visibleList);
    return blt;
}
```

When now removing an entry from my _visibleList i get a System.IndexOutOfRangeException.
I can't figure out why this is happening. Shouldn't the BindingList handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use the [RemoveAt(int index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms132414(v=vs.110).aspx) method of your BindingList make sure that  `index >= 0 && index < blt.Count` otherwise it will throw that exception.

Comment: this wasn't the error but i forgot about that too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.
The _visibleList should have been a BindingList.

So that would result in the following Code

```
private BindingList<T> _visibleList;
```

And then simply return it.

```
public IList GetList()
{
    return _visibleList;
}
```